# How to plot model accuracy and loss for cross-validation with SVM classifier?

Tags: python, svm, cross-validation

Greeting of the day.

I used SVM classifier to classify clickbaits and non-clickbaits.

The code is:

> ```
> // code for training SVM with cross validation
> svm_class = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C = 1.0)
> result_svm= cross_val_score(svm_class, x,encoded_Y, scoring='accuracy', cv = 10)
> print("Accuracy with SVM")
> result_svm.mean()*100
> ```
>
> Ouptut: 94.30 %
>
> ```
> // code for cross-validation test
> y_pred_svm=cross_val_predict(svm_class,x,encoded_Y,cv=10)
>
> //code for confusion matrix
> import numpy as np
> y_s=np.argmax(y, axis=1)
> #print(y_s)
> from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
> cm_svm = confusion_matrix(y_s, y_pred_svm)
> cm_svm
>  Output:  array([[3688,  312],
>         [ 257, 5743]])
> ```

I got two quesitons:

First, how do I plot model accuracy and loss for this SVM?

Second, how do I plot the ROC-AUC curve?